# boost::TIME_UTC(_) with different boost versions

Tags: c++, boost

I just upgraded my project on Windows from boost 1.46 to the current boost 1.52. We have some usages of `boost::TIME_UTC` which I changed to `boost::TIME_UTC_` according to  https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6940.

However, we also build the source on some linux machines with boost 1.49 which doesn't know the `boost::TIME_UTC_`. Is there any suggested way to use boost 1.49 and 1.52 in parallel with TIME_UTC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change everything to `TIME_UTC_`. Then use this:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#if BOOST_VERSION < 105000
#define TIME_UTC_ TIME_UTC
#endif
```

Comment: Actually, it seems, even boost-1.52 does not have boost::TIME_UTC.

Comment: Boost 1.63 also does not provide `boost::TIME_UTC`

Answer (score 2):

We use:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#if BOOST_VERSION < 105000
#include <boost/thread/xtime.hpp>
namespace boost {
  enum xtime_compat {
    TIME_UTC_=TIME_UTC
  };
}
#endif
```

This way you can use `boost::TIME_UTC_`, as in 1.50 onwards.

But not for openSuse, because they decided to merge this change back to 1.49.